# Javascript clock that advances 1h at every button click

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a simple web browser game. In it there is a clock, it doesn't display the real time, but is supposed to start at 9:00 am and avance 1h every time a button is clicked. The problem is that it only works on the first button click and always stays at 10am when I click a button again. I don't understand why.

Here's the code:

```
<script role="script" id="twine-user-script" type="text/twine-javascript">
$(document).ready( function() { 

var callback =  function() {
    displayTime.incrementTime();
};
    $('#onebutton .link-internal').on('click', callback);
    $('#container1 .link-internal').on('click', callback);
    $('#container2 .link-internal').on('click', callback);

    var displayTime = {
        currentTime: new Date(new Date().getUTCFullYear(),
            new Date().getUTCMonth(), 
            new Date().getUTCDay(),
            '9',
            '0',
            '0',
            '0'),
        hoursVal: null,
        hours: function() {
            return displayTime.currentTime.getHours();
        },
        minutesVal: null,
        minutes: function() {
            return displayTime.currentTime.getMinutes();
        },

        meridiem: "am",
        init: function() {
            displayTime.formatDate();
            displayTime.display();
        },
        formatDate: function() {
            if (displayTime.hours() > 12) {
                displayTime.hoursVal = displayTime.hours() - 12; 
                displayTime.meridiem = "pm"; 
            }
            if (displayTime.hours() === 0) {
                displayTime.hoursVal = 12;    
            }
            if(displayTime.hours() < 10) {
                displayTime.hoursVal = "0" + displayTime.hours();
            }
            if(displayTime.minutes() < 10) {
                displayTime.minutesVal = "0" + displayTime.minutes();
            }        
        },

        resetValues: function() {
            displayTime.hoursVal = null;
            displayTime.minutesVal = null;
        //displayTime.secondsVal = null;
    },

    display: function() {
        var clockDiv = document.getElementById('clock');
        clockDiv.innerText = (displayTime.hoursVal === null ? displayTime.hours() : displayTime.hoursVal) + ":" + 
        (displayTime.minutesVal === null ? displayTime.minutes() : displayTime.minutesVal) + " " + 
        displayTime.meridiem;
    },

    incrementTime: function() {
        displayTime.currentTime = new Date(displayTime.currentTime.getTime() + (1000 * 60 * 60));
        displayTime.resetValues();
        displayTime.formatDate();
        displayTime.display();
    }
};

displayTime.init();
setInterval(displayTime.init, 1000);
});
</script>
```

Can anyone point out where the error in my code is?

Comment: I strongly recommend taking a look at [MomentJS](http://momentjs.com/). It is a simple as `moment().add(1, 'hour').format('HH:mm:SS');`

Comment: this is insanely complicated code to increment your game time by one hours....

Answer (score 0):

This [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fkgx1f8q/) works better, but I need your HTML too to give you the exact problem you have:

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var callback = function () {
        displayTime.incrementTime();
    };
    $('#onebutton').on('click', callback);
    $('#container1').on('click', callback);
    $('#container2').on('click', callback);

    var displayTime = {
        currentTime: new Date(new Date().getUTCFullYear(),
        new Date().getUTCMonth(),
        new Date().getUTCDay(),
            '9',
            '0',
            '0',
            '0'),
        hoursVal: null,
        hours: function () {
            return displayTime.currentTime.getHours();
        },
        minutesVal: null,
        minutes: function () {
            return displayTime.currentTime.getMinutes();
        },

        meridiem: "am",
        init: function () {
            displayTime.formatDate();
            displayTime.display();
        },
        formatDate: function () {
            if (displayTime.hours() > 12) {
                displayTime.hoursVal = displayTime.hours() - 12;
                displayTime.meridiem = "pm";
            }
            if (displayTime.hours() === 0) {
                displayTime.hoursVal = 12;
            }
            if (displayTime.hours() < 10) {
                displayTime.hoursVal = "0" + displayTime.hours();
            }
            if (displayTime.minutes() < 10) {
                displayTime.minutesVal = "0" + displayTime.minutes();
            }
        },

        resetValues: function () {
            displayTime.hoursVal = null;
            displayTime.minutesVal = null;
            //displayTime.secondsVal = null;
        },

        display: function () {
            var clockDiv = document.getElementById('clock');
            clockDiv.innerText = (displayTime.hoursVal === null ? displayTime.hours() : displayTime.hoursVal) + ":" + (displayTime.minutesVal === null ? displayTime.minutes() : displayTime.minutesVal) + " " + displayTime.meridiem;
        },

        incrementTime: function () {
            displayTime.currentTime = new Date(displayTime.currentTime.getTime() + (1000 * 60 * 60));
            displayTime.resetValues();
            displayTime.formatDate();
            displayTime.display();
        }
    };

    displayTime.init();
    setInterval(displayTime.init, 1000);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look at this. I have tried to implement this on my page but unfortunately I have not been able to make it work. I will paste the html above, please bear in mind that this is not a 'normal' website, but a game - hence the unusual html.

Comment: Nothing can work with that code. I don't have time to look at that mess. Sorry.